# Cannot detect digit in string using isdigit()

Tags: c++, qt

The task of this function is to check, whether it contains any symbols but digits, spaces, or minuses.

```
bool MainWindow::inputExcp()
    {
        QString inputStr = ui->input->toPlainText();;
        QByteArray ba = inputStr.toLocal8Bit();
        char *myString = ba.data();
        QString warn;
        char space = ' ';
        size_t size = sizeof(myString);
        try{
            for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                if (isdigit(*(myString+i)))
                    continue;
                else if (*(myString+i) == space)
                    continue;
                else if(*(myString+i) == '-')
                    continue;
                else
                    throw *(myString+i);
            }
        }
        catch (char x)
        {
            warn += ("Enter digits, spaces or minuses");
            QMessageBox::warning(this, "Uncorrect input",warn);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I can't understand why this function returns true only for arrays that contain 8 and more elements. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: `size_t size = sizeof(myString);` -- This does not do what you think it does.  This gives you the sizeof char pointer, not the number of characters.   You have the size already in `bd` by just calling `bd.size()`.  Second, if you are using C++ fully, this entire thing is a one-line call to `std::any_of`.

Comment: You probably need to debug.  Why don't you print the char that is thrown?

Comment: `size_t size = sizeof(myString);` should be `size_t size = myString.length();`

Comment: You don't need long long here: `for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < size; i++)`  A QString is limited to ~2GB.

Comment: Off-topic, but why are you using a heavyweight thing such as throwing an exception if someone types in something wrong?  Why not simply detect the error, output a message, and return `false`?

Answer (score 0):

Because the sizeof() function doesnt return the number of elements of a list, it returns the the size of the memory allocated for it.

Comment: *it returns the the size of the memory allocated for it* -- You need to be more specific in this answer.  What exactly does `sizeof` return in this case?

Comment: It returns the size of the QString object which does not include the string which is allocated using new. sizeof() also is a compile time constant. All QStings regardless of how many characters will gave the same sizeof()